# How to generate 4 digit unique id like discord id like #8052

Tags: node.js, database, algorithm, postgresql, web-applications

```
 DECLARE @chars NCHAR(36)
SET @chars = N'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

DECLARE @result NCHAR(4)
SET @result = SUBSTRING(@chars, CAST((RAND() * LEN(@chars)) AS INT) + 1, 1)
            + SUBSTRING(@chars, CAST((RAND() * LEN(@chars)) AS INT) + 1, 1)
            + SUBSTRING(@chars, CAST((RAND() * LEN(@chars)) AS INT) + 1, 1)
            + SUBSTRING(@chars, CAST((RAND() * LEN(@chars)) AS INT) + 1, 1)

SELECT @result
```

i try this but it's too long Im using nodejs and posgresql

Comment: What is a "discord id"? Show an example. State what the constraints are. It is unclear why you have strange string of alpha chars in your question.

Comment: like #8016 @jdv

Comment: You should put details in the original question, which can be edited by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41710457/edit) button.

Comment: You just need a random number in a specific range? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2175512/1531971

Comment: Or maybe you are just trying to create a unique identity in SQL? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29581460/1531971

Comment: i want to generate unique id for my users without any range

Comment: You should state that in your question. This is a pretty basic question, though, and is likely answered more than a few times. In your case, I suspect "serial numeric type" might be what you need.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.  It is no longer exclusively yours, as per the license you accepted when you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the id with your Node.js app. Do a random with `Math`

```
Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 4) // You can change the `4` to change the length.
```

It will output a string like this: `92q6`

In details:

```
Math.random() // 0.2433971674181521
Math.random().toString(36) // 0.ghlhdmdypp8bmx6r
```

> The toString method of a number type in javascript takes an optional parameter to convert the number into a given base. If you pass two, for example, you'll see your number represented in binary. Similar to hex (base 16), base 36 uses letters to represent digits beyond 9. By converting a random number to base 36, you'll wind up with a bunch of seemingly random letters and numbers.
>
> — [Chris Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript#comment19592541_8084248)

Comment: hi bro thx for answering how many variation it could produces does it has limit if so how many .

Comment: You're right, if you want to get a real unique random you must use another way. As mentionned in the Math.random() MDN page: "Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security. Use the Web Crypto API instead, and more precisely the window.crypto.getRandomValues() method." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using nodejs, you could use a standard integer in the database, and convert it to base36 when showing it to the user. In javascript, the parameter to [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) on a numer is the base:

```
a = 46656
b = a.toString(36) // b = "1000"
```

And if you want to convert it back from base36 to a number, use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
b = "1000"
c = parseInt(c, 36) // c = 46656
```

If you want the string to be 4 characters, generate a number between 46656 ("1000") and 1679615 ("zzzz").